# C# Creating directory and setting the permissions

Tags: c#, windows

I am trying to use the code below to allow all users be able to modify a folder:

```
class Program
{
    private const string FileName = "test.txt";
    private static readonly string FilePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + "\\TEST\\" + FileName;
    private static readonly string UserName = Environment.UserDomainName;

    static void Main()
    {
        DirectorySecurity securityRules = new DirectorySecurity();

        string dirPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(FilePath);

        securityRules.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("Users", FileSystemRights.Modify, AccessControlType.Allow));

        if (dirPath == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Failure to save local security settings");

        if (!Directory.Exists(dirPath)) Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath, securityRules);

        File.WriteAllText(FilePath, "Test test!");
    }
}
```

After I run the code, the Users is added to the folder, but not with any rights assigned. All the read, write, execute etc. all the check boxes are not checked. Except the Special permissions is checked.

How Can I add a folder with all Modify for all users?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the `Directory.SetAccessControl()`.

Example:

```
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\my\directory");
DirectorySecurity security = directory.GetAccessControl();

security.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(@"MYDOMAIN\JohnDoe", 
                        FileSystemRights.Modify, 
                        AccessControlType.Deny));

directory.SetAccessControl(security);
```

More details in the [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setaccesscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: It works, but if I want Users to be able to read and execute only, than I change the code "FileSystemRights.Modify" to "FileSystemRights.ReadAndExecute" but it still gives the Users modify access. How can I fix that? Thank you.

Comment: Did you tried this: `security.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(@"MYDOMAIN\JohnDoe", FileSystemRights.Modify, AccessControlType.Deny));` ?

Comment: Yes, I did. I tried in my first code on line 22 "securityRules.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("Users", FileSystemRights.Modify, AccessControlType.Allow));"  It just does not work. However, I am wondering what the default access rule when I called "Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath);" is? Is it modify for all Users?

Comment: Make sure windows are not cheating you. 
I tested here putting the permission "Modify" to "Deny" for my user and I noticed that I can no longer delete the folder, but as you can see in this image http://postimg.org/image/qsg5rl2xn/, the options are like you said (just the "Special permission" is checked). Look in the "advanced" option to see the advanced security configurations.

Comment: Yes, the windows are cheating me. When I Advanced, It show me Deny. Thank you so much for your help!