# How to create a virtual directory in IIS Express using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, error-handling, try-catch

Hello I have a method in my controller that looks like this.

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult UploadImage(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
                return HttpNotFound();

            Component c = db.Components.Find((int)id);
            HttpPostedFileBase photo = Request.Files["image"];

            if (photo != null && photo.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var filename = IGT.imagePath + "\\Components\\" + id.ToString() + ".jpg";

                photo.SaveAs(filename);
                c.Image_Url = IGT.baseUrl + "/Content/images/Components/" + id.ToString() + ".jpg";
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            else
            {
                if (Request["imageurl"] != null && Request["imageurl"].Length > 0)
                {
                    // download this file
                    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                    wc.DownloadFile(Request["imageurl"], IGT.imagePath + "\\Components\\" + id.ToString() + ".jpg");
                    c.Image_Url = IGT.baseUrl + "/Content/images/Components/" + id.ToString() + ".jpg";
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }

            }
            HttpPostedFileBase reference = Request.Files["referencefile"];

            if (reference != null && reference.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                // Upload the origin file and create a URL 
                var filename = IGT.contentPath + "\\uploads\\Comp-" + id.ToString() + "-" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(reference.FileName);
                reference.SaveAs(filename);
                c.Reference_Url = IGT.baseUrl + "/Content/uploads/Comp-" + id.ToString() + "-" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(reference.FileName);
                db.SaveChanges();

            }

            return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = id });
        }
```

But currently when it gets to

`photo.SaveAs(filename);`

I receive the error message

**System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\chris\Source\Repos\inventory2.0\PIC_Program_1.0\Content\images\Components\498.jpg**

How can I make a try catch block so that if the folder doesn't exist in IIS Express, it will create it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this code:

```
if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists("your folder")) {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("Your Folder");
            }
```

Also, make sure your IIS user has a read/write access to that folder directory.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the below code to create directory programmatically:

```
 if (!Directory.Exists(appDataPath)) {
     Directory.CreateDirectory(appDataPath);
 }
```

and use `directory.SetAccessControl(security);` method to set the permission to that folder.

please refer the below links for more detail:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.createdirectory?view=netframework-4.8

[C# Creating directory and setting the permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34752657/c-sharp-creating-directory-and-setting-the-permissions)

https://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2016/02/folder-permission.html