# How to give permission to create directory with c#

Tags: c#, windows, known-folders

here's my code

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\ExtractedContent");
using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\ExtractedContent"))
{
    sw.WriteLine($"TITLE: {extractedTitle[0]}");
    sw.WriteLine("CONTENT:");
    sw.Write(extractedContent[0]);
}`
```

Error:

Unhandled exception : System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the access path 'C:\Users\"directory of the program"' is denied.

Comment: If you're not able to write a file to a directory because of Windows permissions (if that's truly the issue), then the same application probably won't have the rights to _assign_ permissions.

Comment: Probably [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34752657/c-sharp-creating-directory-and-setting-the-permissions)
will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was that i didn't gave the file a name

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\ExtractedContent\file.txt(that's the solution)"))
{
    sw.WriteLine($"TITLE: {extractedTitle[0]}");
    sw.WriteLine("CONTENT:");
    sw.Write(extractedContent[0]);
}
```